# How to create a new list based on the values of the existing list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python.

Let's say I have a list like this :

```
randomList = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

How to filter the values of above list such that the new resultant list has the values according to the condition mentioned.

For example :

Lets say I want to create a new list of all the numbers `n * 2` in randomList such that `n%2 != 0`. Therefore, the new list should look something like this :

```
newList = [6, 10, 14, 22]
```

I can do this by using a `for` loop and using `append` command, but is there a better way to this in python?

p.s - I am a beginner.

Comment: The answer is list comprehensions. Please search for list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that in one simple line.

```
randomList = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]

newList = [n*2 for n in randomList if n%2 != 10]
```

That's it.

Now the values in `newList` would be :

```
newList = [6, 10, 14, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> [ n*2 for n in randomList if n % 2]
[6, 10, 14, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list comprehension` :

```
newlist = [2*i for i in randomList if i % 2 != 0]
```